# AndroidAPI.metadata() Is Null. How to Fix It?

Tags: java, android, dropbox-api

I have been googling and many people seem to have the same problem but no one seems to have a solution, so I'm asking here as it is my last hope to get this issue solved.
I need to list all the files in my App's folder (my aspp doesn't use Full Dropbox Mode). I got this snippet and been trying it for hours but no matter what I do, it always throws a NullPointerException. I have tried even with playing with the parameters but no luck.

How could I go about solving this problem? Could it actually be a ICS issue? I'm running this in a phone running a 4.0.3 custom ROM.

The snippet is below:

```
        try {
        Entry entries = mDBApi.metadata("/", 0, null, true, null);
        for (Entry e : entries.contents)
        {
            if (!e.isDeleted)
            {
                Log.i("Is Folder",String.valueOf(e.isDir));
                Log.i("Item Name",e.fileName());
            }
        }
    } catch (DropboxException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        Log.i("Pointer", "Null pointer");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind haha. I put that code on onCreate(), but little detail: The mDAPi initialization was below that block of code, hence the NullPointerException.

Haha, I feel so dumb.

Comment: If it works now, don't forget to close this question by validating your own answer. Thank you.